# Model for a spread of rumor equation

Tags: calculus

I need to find the function of the below dataset and I am assuming that I should use the function for a spread of rumor (though of course it could be other function types):

$$p(x) = \frac{1}{1+ae^{-kx}},$$

where $p(x)$ is the proportion of the population that has heard the rumor at time $x$ and $a$ and $k$ are positive constants.

What is the function that would fit best the dataset?

```
x      y
1      1
2      1
3      3
4      6
5      10
6      17
7      24
8      28
9      31
10     33
11     34
12     34
```

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the equation.

Comment: See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Plug in some $(x,y)$ pair, say, $(4,6)$, to get an equation in the two unknowns, $k$ and $a$. Then plug in another pair, say, $(8,28)$, to get another such equation. Then do some algebra to solve that pair of two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: You haven't, by any chance, studied "least squares fitting", have you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GerryMyerson its not about just simply plugging some x and y values into some random equation.

Comment: You gave the form of the function you want. That's not random; it's given. By you.

Answer (score 0):

There exists no pair of values $a,k$ such that the equation $y=\frac{1}{1+ae^{-kx}}$ would generate the table you provide. It is enough to just look at the first three lines of the table. According to those three lines, we should have

$$\begin{align}1&=\frac{1}{1+ae^{-k}}\\
1&=\frac{1}{1+ae^{-2k}}\\
3&=\frac{1}{1+ae^{-3k}}\end{align}$$

Multiplying all three equations by the denominator and simplifying, that gives

$$\begin{align}ae^{-k}&= 0\\
ae^{-2k}&= 0\\
3ae^{-3k} - 2 &=0\end{align}$$

Just looking at the first equation, we can conclude that, since $e^{-k}\neq 0$, we have $a=0$. However, that means the third equation becomes $0 = 3\cdot 0\cdot e^{-3k} -2 = 0-2=-2$, a contradiction.

Comment: It's my first time using math StackExchange so there were a few formatting issues. I changed my equation. I need to find the function of this given dataset and I am assuming that I should use the above function that I've stated, which is 1/(1+ae^-kt).

Comment: @hanzo I fixed my answer, the point still stands, you cannot find $a,k$ such that the equation produces the data in the table.

Comment: The exact thing that I need to do is actually to find the best function for the given dataset. I am assuming it could be the function for a spread of rumor, but it could also be other types of functions as well, such as exponential, logarithmic, etc.

Comment: @hanzo What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: it means that I have to find the function that will best fit my data. For example: linear, polynomial, rational, radical, exponential, logarithmic, unlimited growth, limited growth, decay, etc.

Comment: @hanzo How do you determine which function "best" fits the data?

Comment: I have no idea. I am just assuming that I might be able to use a function for a spread of a rumor but not really sure if that's the correct function. That's why I am asking this question here.

Comment: @hanzo Then your question is not about mathematics, really. It's about whatever field the data comes from. Only that field can tell you what the "proximity function" is, i.e. how you define how close a function is to the data. And you NEED that function to answer the question. In fact, once you have it, your question becomes about mathematics. But before that, it is not.

Comment: If you have no idea what you mean by "best fit", han, then how do you know that the constant function $73$ isn't the best fit? If you have no conception of what makes one function a better fit than another, then you have no way to answer your question; you don't even have a coherent question.